# How to filter on a Kafka Dstream in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a list of topics as an argument.

**stream** is a *Kafka DStream object* and is subscribed to **topicsArr**.

I want to filter each DStream based on key and do some transformation on top of individual DStream without breaking the distributed nature of processing.

When I try to do this I encounter

> Object Not Serializable error

Below is the snippet :

```
topicsArr.map(y => {
     stream
      .filter(x => x.key() == y)
      .map(x => x.value())
      .foreachRDD(rdd =>
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
          println "rdd.count()" //More code goes here
     })
})
```

Comment: Is it fine that your final step in the `.map` returns `Unit`? Did you try to remove steps to find out which specific step fails?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...
That may be the reason for it